# Случайный вывод фраз из массива

Tags: javascript, html

Как реализовать в коде мою задумку (я просто новичок и сам не понимаю)? При загрузке страницы выбирается случайная фраза из массива и выводится на экран. Сейчас у меня есть `<p class="ui_txt02">Вы сегодня лучше всех</p>`. Как вместо "Вы сегодня лучше всех" скрипт выводил другую фразу (из представленных в массиве) каждый раз случайно.

Comment: использовать [рандом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) - который будет являтся индексом вашего массива

Comment: Пример https://jsfiddle.net/o6w0kh59/

Comment: а как выходные данные поместить в ui_txt02?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.queryElement() - чтобы достать из документа первый элемент который содержит указанный селектор
Math.random() - для генераций рандомного числа
textContent - чтобы задать текстовое содержимое элемениа

```js
const inspirationalQuotes = [
  'Вы сегодня лучше всех.',
  'Вы должны быть таким, каким хотите увидеть мир.',
  'Кто боится страданий, тот страдает уже от своей боязни.',
  'На самом деле, жизнь проста, но мы настойчиво ее усложняем.',
  'В поисках счастья для других мы находим его для себя.',
  'Лучше умереть значимой смертью, чем жить бессмысленной жизнью.'
];

const replaceQuotes = document.querySelector('.ui_txt02');

window.onload = () => {
  // Сохранить длину массива как переменную
  let inspirationalQuotesSize = inspirationalQuotes.length;
  // Генерируем рандомное число от 0 до количество записей в массиве
  let randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * inspirationalQuotesSize);
  // Добавляем фразу в нам элемент ui_txt02
  replaceQuotes.textContent = inspirationalQuotes[randomQuote];
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.ui_txt02 {
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 64px;
}
```

```html
<p class="ui_txt02"></p>
```

Comment: Почему вы используете `let` вместо `const` внутри функции?

Comment: @OliverPatterson а вы знаете различия между `let` и `const`? Я имею в виду что мне нужна данная переменная только в пределах функций

Comment: @OliverPatterson если вы про то что можно сохранять размер массива как `const` глобально то вы правы

Comment: Да, я знаю в чем различие, и не вижу в данном коде смысла использовать где либо `let`.